# Send an event/callback from VLC to NodeJS to determine if the video is done playing

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, vlc

I am creating an HTML5 player which plays a number of videos on a random order with the following conditions:

- If the resolution of that video is 1024x768 (standard mode), the video will be played on the webpage.
- If the video resolution is on 1920x1080 (fullscreen mode), VLC will open up to play that video on fullscreen.

Everything is on synchronous process since only one video has to be played whether its on standard or fullscreen mode. I am using NodeJS to handle the current flow of the program.

So far, I am able to play videos on VLC via CVLC (an npm package) for fullscreen mode, However, I need an event/callback from VLC that tells NodeJS that the video has ended so it can move on to the next video.

This is what I've been working on so far just to prove the idea . . .

```
const express = require('express');
const cvlc = require('cvlc');
const getVideoDuration = require('node-video-duration');

// Initialize Express
const app =  express();

// Fullscreen Play Route
app.post('/fullscreen-play', (req, res) => {

   // Initialize VLC Player
   const player = new cvlc();

   // This (catched) is the video filename from frontend ajax post request
   let catched = req.body.file; request
   let video = `public/${catched}`;

   // getVideoDuration from node-video-duration
      getVideoDuration(video)
        .then((duration) => {

   // vlanPlayer from cvlc
      vlanPlayer.play(video, function startedLocalFile() {

           // Since I couldn't find the callback/event I needed from VLC this 
           // is how I do things for now just to test but this is very bad.
             setTimeout(() => {
                     console.log("Finished");
                     res.json({running: false});
                     vlanPlayer.destroy();
             }, duration*1000);

        });
    });
});
```

If I'm able to utilize an event/callback from VLC like `stopped` or `onEnded`, etc., I will no longer use the duration variable that changes everytime the `/fullscreen-play` API is called. But if there are other ways to do this without the VLC event/callback I'd be willing to learn and utilize it. Thank you!